# Can I/should I use ES modules for client-side JS files? I use node.js

Tags: javascript

I'm using the latest version of node.js and Chrome.
Node.js still relies on CommonJS to do modules (exports and imports).
The [CommonJS page](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/) that was recommended to me actually says CommonJS is not suitable for client-side and to use ES modules instead. This makes me think I should use them for my websites that I'm creating. Is it possible to do this?

The errors I get when I try to are 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' & unexpected token export' & 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.'

Here are the errors I get when I include `type="module"`:
[image]

Comment: Node.js supports both CommonJS and ES modules.  But not at the same time.

Comment: @GirkovArpa can I get my question re-opened for the fact that I've already implemented the solution in the suggested article and it's not brought me success?

Comment: I can't open or close any questions.  But you just solved your original problem using the `type="module"` approach.  Now you have an entirely new problem which requires a new question (fair warning, it will probably get closed because it's been asked and answered before).

Comment: @GirkovArpa yes I've avoided being lazy and found the solution to host my webpage on a server with this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Answer (score 2):

Write `<script type="module">` instead of `<script>`.